# GORM inheritance tables

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have an abstract domain class:

```
abstract class DomainBase { 
    Date created = new Date(), modified = new Date()
    Long createdBy, modifiedBy
    int dataStatus = 30 
    static mapping = { 
        tablePerSubclass true
        created column: 'erstellt_am'
        createdBy column: 'erstelle_von'
        modified column: 'bearbeitet_am'
        modifiedBy column: 'bearbeitet_von'
        dataStatus column: 'data_status'
    }

    static constraints = { 
        created(nullable: true, display: false)
        modified(nullable: true, display: false)
        modifiedBy(nullable: true, display: false)
        createdBy(nullable: true, display: false)
        dataStatus(nullable: false, display: false)
    }
}
```

and I have some other Classes extending the DomainBase:

```
class foo extends DomainBase {
  String text
  static constraints = {
    importFrom(DomainBase)
  }
}
```

This results in 2 Table `domain_base` and `foo`. The table of Foo doesn't contain the properties of DomainBase.

I want it so that all subclasses have one Table with all the properties of `DomainBase` but `DomainBase` itself should not have an Table.

I tried `tablePerConcreteClass true`, `tablePerHierarchy false` and `tablePerSubclass true` but nothing results in what i want.

So how can I let Hibernate make an Table for every SubClass with the properties of the Abstract Class?

Comment: Move `DomainBase` from `domains` to a package under `src`.

Comment: You're right that would work, but the Mappings is not inherited when I move it to `src`.

Comment: Is there no other solution? I'm not understanding how to use the inheritance for domain Classes and what it is usefull for.

Comment: I have an older Application working with Grails 1.3.9 and there is an Inheritance similar to this and there it's working like i expected it. In the Upper Classe I don't use `tablePer***`.

Comment: Open a ticket in github. It should work in latest grails the same way it works for 1.3.9. Probably an issue in grails. Which version are you using?

Comment: I'm using Grails 2.4.3